# How can i get all images including G+ ones threw android version

Tags: android, google-plus, uri, android-image, bitmapfactory

I use ANDROID_PICK or ANDROID_GET_CONTENT in an app (same behavior with two methods). Minimal supported version is API 11. 
So i've tested my app on different devices and i obtain some URI inconsistent threw android version:

Some of these are:

```
content://com.google.android.apps.photos.contentprovider/url
content://com.google.android.apps.photos.content/url
content://com.android.gallery3d.provider/picasa/item/numbers
...
```

and When i use getContentProvider().openInputStream(uri); to get a stream to give to BitmapFactory, I receive FileNotFoundException.

How can I get all these images threw a single method without depending on Android version? I think that the openInputStream was the good method but it seems to be false.The problem i encounter is only for distant content (Google +) for local content, i get the image and can do what i want with it.

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

So i found what i search for.

To get image from google plus and other sources handle by photos app.

```
MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getContentResolver(), imageUri);
```

imageUri is received from three ways: ACTION_GET_CONTENT, ACTION_PICK or Intent-Filter

For ACTION_GET_CONTENT and ACTION_PICK:

```
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent returnIntent)
{
    if(resultCode == RESULT_OK){
        imageUri = returnIntent.getData();
    }
}
```

For Intent-Filter

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    Intent receiveIntent = getIntent();
    if(receiveIntent != null && receiveIntent.getType() != null && receiveIntent.getType().contains("image/"))
    {
        imageUri = receiveIntent.getParcelableExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM);
    }
}
```